# How to fetch default action in +page.server.ts file in SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit and I've a form on my page. As I need to manipulate the data before it is sent, I cannot use the SvelteKit's default behaviour of form submission (using `action` attribute).

So, according to [this part of the documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-custom-event-listener), I used a simple event listener and then the `fetch` function :

```js
async function handleSubmit(e:Event) {
  const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
  // ... doing some stuff here
  const res = await fetch("?/login", { /* plenty of stuff there */ });
}
```

So the action named "login" in `./+page.server.ts` will be executed.

I have a simple question: **what path do I write (in `fetch`) if I want the default action to be executed, knowing that the current page is in a slug.**

Do I write `fetch("?/")` ? (doesn't work)

Do I write `fetch("?"`) ? (doesn't work)

Obviously I could just name it and problem solved. I'm just wondering if there is a solution and if someone has ever thought about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do this.

Set up the form as usual and [use the `enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance), which can be provided with a callback to intercept and modify the submission.

From the docs:

```html
<form
  method="POST"
  use:enhance={({ form, data, action, cancel }) => {
    // `form` is the `<form>` element
    // `data` is its `FormData` object
    // `action` is the URL to which the form is posted
    // `cancel()` will prevent the submission

    return async ({ result, update }) => {
      // `result` is an `ActionResult` object
      // `update` is a function which triggers the logic that would be triggered if this callback wasn't set
    };
  }}
>
```

If you just want to add data, you do not even have to return anything from the function, e.g.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance, type SubmitFunction } from '$app/forms';

    const onSubmit: SubmitFunction = ({ data }) => {
        data.set('test', 'value');
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" use:enhance={onSubmit}>
  ...
</form>
```

Of course there also is the old fashioned way: Just add `type=hidden` inputs to the form instead. If the data does not have to change, this would be the most robust approach, as it does not require any JS to make the form send the data.

---

As for what the default action is: It's just the current URL, `document.location.href`.

Comment: Thank you, that helps! Although the reason why I am not using `use:enhance` is because I have an input of type `file` that is `multiple` and I want the user to be able to remove a file from the list if he changed his mind. As far as I know it's not possible to manually change the FileList from such input. Does the `SubmitFunction` allows me to change the data **before** it is sent to the server?

Comment: Also, I think you meant `document.location.href` instead of `document.href` because this is `undefined`. I checked and indeed it triggers the default action

Comment: Changing data before it is sent is exactly what the example above does. But if you need asynchronous user interaction you should not be triggering the submit at all. Let the user make any changes they want beforehand. You can render a list of files that allows the user to remove items beforehand and then just `append` the files that should be sent to the `data`. ([REPL example of file list](https://svelte.dev/repl/af3c7f910f96459e8b2414b6c16e07fb?version=3.55.1))